# How to do a thing if user does something with a certain time limit?

Tags: python, time, ursina

I'm trying to make a 3D game but right now just jumping, I have got the jumping working, but I want to do a thing that (for example if speed=10) but if space is pressed 2x within (for example 0.5 seconds) the speed will go up by (for example 2) and if the player doesn't jump 2x times within the 0.5 seconds the speed stays/resets to normal.

So to simplify character speed becomes faster if you press space in certain time and if you don't for it stays 10, for example if I press space/jump and after 1 second do the same, the speed won't go up, but if I press space/jump within seconds <= 0.5 seconds the speed will go up, until I **don't** press it within the time, so if I stop pressing it within seconds <= 0.5 seconds the jump resets to 10 and if I jump --> 0.6 seconds =< seconds the speed stays the same.

And to people who don't know `ursina`, its a python based game engine and you modify the player using this type
---->  `player=FirstPersonController(gravity = (1), speed=10)`

(Not sure but I think the engine is *fully* based on Python. Just so you know.

The engine I'm learning in is "Ursina Engine"

Comment: You can measure time very precisely in Python using functions in the [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#module-time) module. You can also do it with [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) objects.

Comment: @martineau yes, i'm not completely new to python, and i know basics very well any know how to use many modules. I know the time module, and i use it alot, but i have not managed to find out how the module could fix my problem. But actually i have never used threading time, so i will look more into that now. thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to save the timestamp whenever the space is pressed.  Then, every time it is pressed, before updating the timestamp, compare now against the previous timestamp... if it is less than 500ms, then speed up!

Reacting to the user doing nothing is harder.  I have not used ursula, and a quick look at the documentation, I do not see much in the Ursina Engine to help you.

But I have an idea you could try?  When the character is sped up, create an invisible wall to hit. Set the wall up exactly where the character will be in 500ms time, if the user does nothing, they will "collide" with the wall and it will trigger your routine to reduce the speed.  If the user does do something, remove the wall.  Just an idea. Not sure if that will work.  Enjoy!

Comment: oh well its basically a parkour game where you need to jump on platforms or for example trees from Minecraft and on other items from other games etc. I don't know if you are a gamer, but for example in csgo there is kind of that type thing. Can i show u the full code somehow? Should i add it to the question?

Comment: and  i was thinking this type of code somehow:   If keyboard.is_pressed('space') **2 in "seconds": Speed = speed + 1. Else: pass